# Range of poissons ratio

Tags: elasticity

I know the range of poisson's ratio is -1 to 0.5 but how do you arrive at this expression? I am a 11th grade student and I am not too familiar with advanced physics

Comment: It's an experimentally determined range.

Comment: Kyle, this is incorrect. See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a bit lengthy, but can be arrived at using arguments about elastic strain energy. Here is a very detailed explanation:

[Limits of Poisson's ratio in isotropic solid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/limits-of-poissons-ratio-in-isotropic-solid/100233#100233)

This was written at a graduate mechanical engineering level, so I'll simplify it here.

Imagine that there exists a function $\psi$ that describes how much energy is contained in a solid per unit volume. This quantity is a function of material properties and deformation. For a linear elastic, isotropic solid, the material properties are Young's modulus (E), and the Poisson ratio ($\nu$).

One of the assumptions of the theory of elasticity is that the elastic energy $\psi$ is a function that is **strictly increasing** for all conceivable deformations. The details of this assumption are in my other answer (the link), but it turns out that $\nu$ can only be in the interval

$$
-1 < \nu < \frac{1}{2}
$$

I hope this clears up your question at an appropriate level. Let me know in the comments if not!

Comment: I wonder if there are real life examples of matrieals with negative $\nu$. Great answer BTW.

Comment: Thanks! What you're thinking of are called "auxetic" materials. This property tends to correspond to highly (micro)structured materials. One classical example is a non-convex hexagon. Here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxetics

Comment: There are quite a few auxetic metamaterials known to us. Monolayer graphene for example at finite temperature exhibits a universal negative poisson ratio of about -1/3 (so do all thermally fluctuating tethered membranes). One can easily construct an auxetic structure even out of paper. Look up Miura-Ori.

Answer (score 0):

Poisson's ratio can be expressed in terms of Young's modulus $E$, Bulk modulus $K$ and Shear modulus $G$. I hope you know how do arrive at these relationships;

$$ G=\frac{E}{2(1+\nu)}$$

$$ K=\frac{E}{3(1-2\nu)}$$

$E, K$ and $G$ and all **NOT** less than zero.

From the equation of $G$ you can see that it's the value of $v=-1$ which would make the denominator $0$ and $G$ very large. That's the limit for $G$.

And from the equation of $K$ it's the value of $v=0.5$ that makes the denominator $0$ and $K$ very large. The limit for $K$.

Therefore $v$ can only fall between $-1$ and $0.5$.